# multiprocessing vs threading in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I trying to test the example at [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html) changing it from threading to multiprocessing.

Running this (the original example) in jupyter notebook, will display a progress bar that fills up in some time.

```
import threading
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time
progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)

def work(progress):
    total = 100
    for i in range(total):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        progress.value = float(i+1)/total

thread = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(progress,))
display(progress)
thread.start()
```

If I change the code to multiprocessing, the progress bar appears, but does not fill up:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time
progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)

def work(progress):
    total = 100
    for i in range(total):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        progress.value = float(i+1)/total

p = mp.Process(target = work, args=(progress,))
display(progress)
p.start()
```

If I modify the above by adding a `print(i)` in the workers loop, the progress bar magically starts to fill up.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time
progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)

def work(progress):
    total = 100
    for i in range(total):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        progress.value = float(i+1)/total

p = mp.Process(target = work, args=(progress,))
display(progress)
p.start()
```

Is this a bug or is there something fundamental I am not getting here?

### Edit (system info)

OS is Ubuntu 18.04

```
$jupyter --version 
4.4.0
```

```
import sys; sys.version 
3.7.0 (default, Oct 15 2018, 10:26:13) \n[GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, got a pickling error. What OS/Python version are you running?

Comment: `jupyter --version` is `4.4.0` and `import sys; sys.version` is `'3.7.0 (default, Oct 15 2018, 10:26:13) \n[GCC 7.3.0]'`

Comment: OS is an Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Processes don't share state the way threads do. When you progress as an argument to Process, it gets copied by the newly created processes. Each process will have it's own progress bar and the one you care about, the one in the master process, will never receive updates.

Comment: Why would then adding a single print statement inside the process alter the behaviour of the progress bar? This is what I kind of fail to see.