# update widget from process in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, jupyter, ipywidgets

similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335524/multiprocessing-vs-threading-in-jupyter-notebook?newreg=939c8bba85184ac2829ec9620cf94506)

Creating a float progress widget and updating it in another process,
Why adding a print statement updates the progress bar?
Can this be done without the print statement?

Jupyter version: 5.3

```
import sys; sys.version
```

'3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) \n[GCC 7.3.0]'

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time
progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)

def work(progress):
    total = 100
    for i in range(total):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        progress.value = float(i+1)/total

p = mp.Process(target = work, args=(progress,))
display(progress)
p.start()
```

Comment: `progress.value = float(i+1)/total` is the part that updates the progress bar, the `print` statement has no effect on the bar.

Comment: if there is no print statement the progress widget wont change ( work() is running in a different process)

Comment: You are quite right! Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the `tqdm` module? It does almost exactly what you want, and there is a jupyter notebook extension:

Ex:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    pass
```

prints this nice progress bar which updates every iteration:

[image: tqdm]